# Reuse result of stochastic python-igraph layout for future plotting

Tags: python, layout, igraph

I can successfully draw a nice network using the `kk` layout. Unfortunately, as `kk` is a stochastic layout, it looks different every time I plot it.

Is there a way to plot it twice with the same vertex and node arrangement but varying the visual style? I would like to visualize changes by changing the vertex colors and showing both plots side-by-side. Of course, in the future I might be interested in modifying edges too but this is not an issue right now.

I'm completely fine with the fact that the layout changes for every run of my programm, it should just plot it consistently within one run.

I can plot it twice if I save the resulting SVG but of course modyfining the underlying graph would be more elegant than just tweaking the raw SVG.

This plots the same layout twice but only as SVG:

```
s = cairo.SVGSurface(None, 800, 800)
model = ig.plot(g, **visual_style,
    vertex_label=[label_for_title(vertex[1]['title']) for vertex in enumerate(g.vs)],
    edge_color=[color_for_rating(edge[1]['rating']) for edge in enumerate(g.es)],
    target=s,
    mark_groups=action_systems)._repr_svg_()

display(SVG(model))
display(SVG(model))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, because igraph lets you store the layout of the vertices as an object: `my_layout = g.layout('kk')`.

So you can plot your graph g multiple times with the same layout:

```
my_layout = g.layout('kk')
igraph.plot(g,layout=my_layout)
#now change g and/or the visual style
g.delete_edges([0,3,4])
igraph.plot(g,layout=my_layout,vertex_color=['blue' for _ in g.vs])
```

The new plotted graph will have the same vertex positions but now a few edges will be gone and all the vertices will be blue, naturally.